# How to add a new tab using FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, java-8, fxml

I'm really lost as to how to add tabs in FXML and Java using my controller class, can someone take a look and tell me how it'd be done?

Here's my main class:
http://pastebin.com/mHkqYe5D
Here's my fxml class:
http://pastebin.com/pHLJJRWp
Here's my controller class:
http://pastebin.com/dp0Yb5Eg

Comment: I tried adding my code to this site but it was being difficult, so I used pastebin. I hope that' sokay.

Comment: It would be better if you would post your code here.

Comment: It wouldn't let me, I tried and it all looked properly formatted but it kept saying it was properly indented after doing that a few times I just decided to pastebin it. StackOverFlow should really consider using [code][/code] tags like on forums instead of this 4 spaces method.

Comment: There is the {} button, which helps with formatting code. Please post your code here. We can help you then with the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for *adding* the tab looks fine.

```
public Tab tab = new Tab();

public void menuItemNewTab(ActionEvent event){
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
}
```

However, you seem to be trying to add the ***same*** Tab object with each click. I did a quick test and I think that is your problem. Create a new instance every time you add a new Tab:

```
public void menuItemNewTab(ActionEvent event){
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab());
}
```

Comment: Oh wow it works! I had an error in my FXML so it wasn't working, I had tried this code before though lol I tried a lot of things....

Do you know how to add things inside that tab? I'm making a notepad application it's kinda useless unless each tab can have a scrollpane and textarea :/ I've tried a few things to get it in it but I can't really figure it out.

I tried putting new TextArea() inside the call to the Tab() but it didn't work...:/

Comment: Try tab.contentProperty().set(somePane); where somePane is a pane (like AnchorPane) that contains the TextArea.